# Shell script-duplicate records

Tags: shell

I am facing problem in removing the duplicate entries.(I am not good in Shell!).here is the situation-
Application creates a flat text file. Each line is one record and each field is seperated by delimiter "~|"(quotes excluded). So record looks like-

```
Field1~|Field2~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~|
```

There are some records which are duplicate.Duplicate record is decided  by value of field- Field2. How to write shell script/awk/sed to remove duplicate records based on this criteria? Script then has to write output to some other file.
I could have done this in application itself but due to performance problem it can not be done.
Thanks for help.

Input file

```
Field1~|ABA~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~|
Field1~|PQR~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~|
Field1~|XYZ~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~|
Field1~|ABA~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~|
Field1~|RST~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~|
Field1~|PQR~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~|
```

Output should be-

```
Field1~|ABA~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~|
Field1~|PQR~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~|
Field1~|XYZ~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~|
Field1~|RST~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~|
```

(order of the records doesn't matter.)

Comment: show a more concrete example/sample of this input file. If field 2 has a lot of duplicates, how should your output look like. ?

Comment: Input file can have lot of duplicates.In such case, only one unique record will be written to output file.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly, but is this what you're looking for?:

test.txt:

```
Field1~|Field2~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~|
foo~|Field2~|bar~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~|
Field1~|foobar~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~|
```

Calling [sort](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/sort.1.php):

```
sort --field-separator="~" --key 2,2 --unique test.txt
```

Results in:

```
Field1~|Field2~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~|
Field1~|foobar~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~|
```

Comment: Thanks.Input file Field1~|ABA~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~| Field1~|PQR~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~| Field1~|XYZ~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~| Field1~|ABA~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~| Field1~|RST~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~| Field1~|PQR~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~| Output should be- Field1~|ABA~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~| Field1~|PQR~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~| Field1~|XYZ~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~| Field1~|RST~|Field3~|Field4~|Field5~|Field6~|Field7~|

Comment: The sort method works with your test case. I keep my example, since it illustrates that only the second field is taken into account when deciding if two lines are equal.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all duplicates

```
nawk -F'~|' '{a[$2]++;b[$2]=$0}END{for(i in a) if (a[i]==1){print b[i]} }' file
```

If you want to keep only one version of duplicate record

```
nawk -F'~|' '!a[$2]++' file
```

Comment: Thanks.but second one gives an syntax error.(I am using Solaris).The first one does not display any result.There are the records-ABCD~|PQRS~|1234~|BLR
PQRS~|GSG~|7281~|KLP
NPQS~|NCX~|9192~|VBN

Comment: If you are using Solaris, use `nawk`. put in the field delimiter. I forgot about that. Also, update all important information in your question, not in the comments.